# Replace each letter in more one word JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace, each, words, letter

I want to replace each letter in more one word like this example:
if user typed `#(*@$^ $^*` by the code I want to change each letter to `cinema man`. Explaining more - I want to make a map like this:

```js
"#" = "c";
"(" = "i";
"*" = "n";
"@" = "e";
"$" = "m";
"^" = "a";
```

How I can make that process with JavaScript?

Comment: do you have a fixed mapping of letters? as you mentioned in your post : "#" = "c"; "(" = "i"; "*" = "n"; "@" = "e"; "$" = "m"; "^" = "a"

Comment: @Sreekanth sorry I haven't a fixed map

Comment: so how do you convert from "#" => "C"?

Comment: @Sreekanth it just an example,, can you help coz all answers related to mapping only

Comment: I dont understand when you mention this is an example. Whats you r logic to convert #(*@$^ $^* =? "cinema man" if you dont have a specific mapping of letters?

Comment: @Sreekanth I have a specific mapping of letters from English letters to Italian letters

Comment: in that case, what you need is already answered by others. All of the answers are the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to map those specific characters, you can do something like this:

```
var myMap = {
    "#": "c",
    "(": "i", 
    "*": "n"
};

var string = "#(*";

var newLetters = string.split('').map(function(letter){
    return myMap[letter];
});

newLetters.join('');
```

You just need to create an object to reference it's key-value pair.

Edit: Obviously you can fix this to work to your liking, just something I whipped up to illustrate the over all idea.

Comment: This was the first and a perfectly fine answer, why the downvote?

Comment: @tmslnz I'd like to know as well.

Comment: @tmslnz he has missed a case when the character doesnt match to anything in myMap. But yea that should be a suggestion not a downvote.

Comment: Again, over all idea, I wasn't going to write their code for them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a object in order to store the mapping. Now parse the string and replace each word with its mapped work. Here is a working demo:

```js
var mapping = {
  "#": "c",
  "(": "i",
  "*": "n",
  "@": "e",
  "$": "m",
  "^": "a"
};

var string = "#(*@$^ $^*";
var output = string.split("").map(function(el) {
  if(mapping.hasOwnProperty(el))
    return mapping[el];
  
  return el;
}).join("");

alert(output);
```